# c++ global class constructor in lib file

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have the following project generating foo.lib.

```
//foo.h:
class A
{
public:
    A();
    static A* i;
};

//foo.cpp:
A* i = 0;
A g_A_instance; 
A::A()
{
    //this constructor is not called :(
    i = this;
}
```

I have another project generating an exe file that links with foo.lib. It seems that the constructor A::A() is not called. How can i make this work , are there some compiler options that i'm missing?

PS: I used visual studio compiler 2008

Thanks,
Raxvan.

Comment: what do you mean its not called?? Are you getting an error? What code do you have in the exe for instantiating it?

Comment: I have a breakpoint, a printf in the constructor and none of them are working.Also when the code runs the static variable i is NULL all the way

Answer (score 0):

If I change

```
A* i = 0;
```

to

```
A* A::i = 0;
```

so it will link, the constructor was called properly for me in VS2005, default options. Does this exact example reproduce the problem on your compiler?

Comment: I found the problem , because A is not used in the main project , the compiler "remove" any A related data, if i use A (even a simple pointer) , then everything works fine.